# Using Google Plus API to store stream data in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, cron, google-plus

I've been playing with the Google+ API PHP starterkit.  My ultimate goal is to run a cron job on my server that uses the Google+ API to grab the activity data, then store it in a MYSQL database-- where I can then dynamically update a twitter-like feed on a website.

Is this a possible/practical way of mining a Google+ profile's public stream? If not, what do you suggest as a good alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a good way to me.

One thing you have to keep in mind though is that there is no easy way to check if an activity has been deleted after you have added it to your database. You would have to check with `$plus->activities->get($activityId)` for each of the activities you want to display to see if it still exists (unless of course you don't mind them appearing on your website).

Apart from that your solution will work fine.

Comment: I think a developing a cron job to scan the database periodically will keep the entries synchronized.